# Regex: Detect Phone numbers that are separated by dashes (-) and/or spaces

Tags: regex

I am trying to recognize these types of phone number inputs:

1. 0172665476
2. +6265476393
3. +62-65476393
4. +62-654-76393
5. +62 65476393

While my regex: `(?:\d+\s*)+` can recognize the 1st 2 sample values, it recognizes the last 3 sample values as multiple matches in each line, instead of recognizing the number as a whole.

How can I modify this to support multiple dashes and/or spaces and still recognize it as 1 whole number instead of multiple matches?

Comment: @Delgan Close! it includes a trailing space if there's any space after the number: "Hi my number is 0172665476 okay?"

Comment: check this https://regex101.com/r/wxIiPs/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
^\+?\d+(?:[\s-]\d+)*\b
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `^\+?`: Match optional `+` at start
- `\d+`: match 1+ digits
- `(?:[\s-]\d+)*`: Match 0 or more groups that start with whitespace or `-` followed by 1+ digits
- `$`: End (Replaced by word boundary as if there are trailing spaces, that match would be missed.)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
(?:[\d +-]+)+
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work as per your reqt: (If there are trailing spaces, this regex will ignore.)

Regex: '^(?:[\d +-]+)\b'

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match either 10 digits without a leading plus sign or match the pattern with a `+`, and optional space or hyphen:

```
(?:\d{10}|\+\d{2}[- ]?\d{3}-?\d{5})\b
```

That will match:

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\d{10}` Match 10 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `\+\d{2}[-\s]?\d{3}-?\d{5}` Match `+`, 2 digits, optional whitespace char or `-`, 3 digits, optional `-`, 5 digits
- `)\b` Close non capturing group and word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uVsf82/1)

If your language supports negative lookbehinds you could prepend [`(?<!\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/uVsf82/2) which checks that what comes before is not a non-whitespace character.