# MySQL REGEXP That Will Detect Numbers Separated by a Space

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to create a REGEXP pattern that will check if a string contains a set of numbers separated by a space. I have tried the 4 statements below. They all return 0. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
SELECT '0630 3062' REGEXP '^[0-9]{4} [[:space:]] [0-9]{4}$';

SELECT 'Employee 346 retrad: 0630 3062' REGEXP '[0-9]{4} [[:space:]] [0-9]{4}';

SELECT 'Employee 346 retrad: 0630 3062' REGEXP '[0-9]+ [[:space:]] [0-9]+';

SELECT 'Employee 346 retrad: 0630 3062 1657 in July Assessment' REGEXP '[0-9]+ [[:space:]] [0-9]+';
```

The statements are also in this [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uGkY-TtB)

I have looked at a [similar post/thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54009879/regex-detect-phone-numbers-that-are-separated-by-dashes-and-or-spaces) and the two answers there don't work;  the query still returns 0 instead of 1. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually matching 2 times a space and a single `[[:space:]]` in the middle.

You want to match only a single `[[:space:]]`

```
SELECT '0630 3062' REGEXP '^[0-9]{4}[[:space:]][0-9]{4}$';

SELECT 'Employee 346 retrad: 0630 3062' REGEXP '[0-9]{4}[[:space:]][0-9]{4}';

SELECT 'Employee 346 retrad: 0630 3062' REGEXP '[0-9]+[[:space:]][0-9]+';

SELECT 'Employee 346 retrad: 0630 3062 1657 in July Assessment' REGEXP '[0-9]+[[:space:]][0-9]+';
```

Comment: I didn't know that the literal spaces between different character sets/ranges mattered. Thanks; Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove black spaces from regex:

`^[0-9]{4}[[:space:]][0-9]{4}$` returns 1 in first statement